# Удаление указателей c++

Tags: c++

Чтобы сдать задачу, мне нужно для каждого new, после использования выполнить delete. В этой части кода у меня вызывается new для каждой строчки матрицы - и потом выделенная память не освобождается. Куда здесь засунуть delete? Пробовал после std::fill писать delete [] matrix[i], но выдает ошибку.

```
template<class T>
T** createMatrix(int ncount, int mcount) {
     T** matrix = new T*[ncount];
     for (int i = 0; i < ncount; ++i) {
        matrix[i] = new T[mcount];
        std::fill(matrix[i], matrix[i] + mcount, T());
     }
     return matrix;
```

Answer (score 4):

> Куда здесь засунуть delete?

В вашем случае необходимо предусмотреть специальную функцию `releaseMatrix(ncount, matrix);`, в которой будет то, что написал Denis Rakitin

А по-хорошему - в деструктор типа-обертки `Matrix`, который будет владеть указателями. Когда умирает объект Matrix (выход из метода, смерть класса-владельца, чьим членом был объект Matrix или вообще исключение), тогда автоматически освобождается и память. [RAII](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

```
template<typename T> class Matrix {
public:
   typedef T      value_type;
   typedef size_t dim_size;

   Matrix(dim_size n, dim_size m) 
        : _n(n), _m(m), 
          _buffer(new T[ n * m ])
   {
   }
   ~Matrix() {
      delete [] _buffer;
   }

   dim_size getRowsCount() const { return _n; }
   dim_size getColsCount() const { return _m; }

   T& at(dim_size row, dim_size col) {
      return _buffer[ row * _m + col ];
   }

private:
   const int _n, _m;
   T *_buffer;

   Matrix(const Matrix<T>& other) =delete;
   Matrix(Matrix<T>&& other) =delete;
   Matrix& operator=(const Matrix<T>& other) =delete;
   Matrix& operator=(Matrix<T>&& other) =delete;
};
```

Либо просто использовать умный указатель с custom deleter:

```
template<class T>
using MatrixPtr = std::unique_ptr<T**,std::function<void(T***)>;

template<class T>
MatrixPtr& createMatrix(int ncount, int mcount) {
    T **matrix = new T*[ncount];
    for (int i = 0; i < ncount; ++i) {
        matrix[i] = new T[mcount]; // допустим, что мы не боимся std::bad_alloc
        std::fill(matrix[i], matrix[i] + mcount, T());
    }

    return MatrixPtr(matrix, [ncount](T ***matrix) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < ncount; ++i) {
                                    delete[] *matrix[i];
                                }
                                delete[] *matrix;
                            });
}
```

Comment: Насчет RAII: если в конструкторе вылетит исключение нехватки памяти где-то в цикле, то всё равно будет утечка. Поэтому выделять следовало бы единым блоком, это и для производительности полезно. Оу .. не сразу заметил, что так оно и есть у Вас :) Хотя от деструктора можно вовсе избавиться, используя `unique_ptr` в качестве члена.

Comment: Вот только структуру данных  Вы переделали... Возможно,  массив  указателей для чего-то нужен (вряд ли автору и в этой задачке, но в общем случае так бывает)

Comment: @avp, да, конечно, во втором случае переделал вполне сознательно. При необходимости код можно подвергнуть небольшому тюнингу и получить желаемый интерфейс к данным, не теряя при этом удобства "полуавтоматического" управления памятью.

Comment: @free_ze у вас в первом случае из-за того что не учитывается [the rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) будет segmentation failt например в случае присвоения первой матрицы вторую и удаления после этого второй и обращения затем к первой.

Comment: @arammis, спасибо, явно отключил, чтобы не загромождать код.

Answer (score 2):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ncount; ++i) 
    delete[] matrix[i];
 delete[] matrix;
```

Но смысла делать это в createMatrix нет.